# Angular 4 serve static html page

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6

In my simple web application on Angular 4, I have static pages like **about us**, **contact us** etc and if this static pages included as component the size of angular app will increase.

Is there any way to display this static pages via angular app on demand?

Comment: You can create separate modules for them and load the via lazy loading. That would be ideal way. They won't be downloaded until called.

Comment: Could you please give a link to refer?

Comment: https://alligator.io/angular/lazy-loading/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lazy loading for this.

Basic idea is to create an module for all your static pages.

This would be ideal way. They won't be downloaded until called.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  ...      
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
  ...
];
```

Import is as :

```
RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

Where `PagesModule` is your module name to be lazy loaded.

FYI : [Lazy Loading Module](https://alligator.io/angular/lazy-loading/)

Comment: so each static page content should be as a separate component in pages folder, right?